# xfce desktop environment ubuntu 20.04 - desktop not loading

Tags: xubuntu, dell, xfce, intel, .desktop

right-click does nothing, the panel shows up but the desktop icons don't though it inverts if I mess with the desktop settings manager, either way tabs/windows aren't responsive or behave abnormally.

`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` changed nothing, neither did uninstalling and reinstalling both XFCE and xubuntu https://www.fosslinux.com/44293/how-to-install-and-uninstall-xfce-on-ubuntu.htm
and same goes for deliting  ~/.cache/sessions/ and ~/.config/xfce4
`rm -R ~/.cache/sessions/*` `xfdesktop`.

I've updated to 20.04 almost a year ago and everything worked, so I don't think that's the issue. it used to load fine through recovery mode.

if any more informations are needed, please ask, I'm not very good at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alt+F2 launch compiz. that was it for me